# Is there any tool/utility to find the dependency between JSP and form action class for Struts2 framework?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Is there any tool/utility to find the dependency between JSP and form action class for Struts2 framework?

For example if in Struts2 framework JSP has form action and action class is defined in struts config file.

Is there any tool which reads the JSP file and config file and gives dependency like:

`Login.jsp` depends on action class: `com.user.action.WelcomeUserAction`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How you would like to see an output of such tool?

Comment: @AleksandrM: are you thinking of building one ? :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Why not? :D

Comment: I see patterns in the noise... :D

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward, especially if you don't aren't using the convention plugin at all; a simple matter of looking for form/action/link tags, and aligning them with the S2 config. I don't have one of these for S2, although I had a fairly extensive tool for documenting S1 apps.

Comment: @Dave Newton Please can you share the tool details

Comment: @AleksandrM: Any format should be fine. For example map of key being JSP and value being action class